# angularjs not showing International Accent Marks and Diacriticals

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

I have a problem with my app, which i made with cordova apache and angularjs. The problem is, that the International Accent Marks and Diacriticals not showing correct. There is a problem with "à" all other Html codes showing up correctly!

When I showing the following text :

```
C&#39;est tout &agrave; fait juste.
```

it comes out like this :

```
C'est toutagrave; fait juste.
```

But it should be like this :

```
C'est tout à fait juste.
```

There is only a problem with the à!

This is my code:

```
 <div class="learnBox" ng-show="view.learnData.VisibleSetting.ShowQuestion" ng-bind-html="view.learnData.Card.FrontText | unsafe"></div>
```

And in the app.js I have:

```
   app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
```

Does someone know this problem? How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this solution worked:

```
var elemfolderName = document.createElement('textarea');
elemfolderName.innerHTML = "C&#39;est tout &agrave; fait juste.";
var  folderName = elemfolderName.value;
```

And then I save folderName to sqlite3 db...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you are using UNICODE HTML in `&#39;`

But you are using html in `&agrave;`

If UNICODE is working well, use `&#224;` instead of `&agrave;`

Comment: I have this also in my code     <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: try removing your second meta, and dont close the first one

Comment: I tried allready with removing second meta, but not working. And not closing the first one was not the solution. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not angularjs it is sqlite. It cut of from $agrave; the $ when i save it to db.